# How do I contain my JavaScript game in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, craftyjs

In my HTML, I have a section in which I have JavaScript that adds an event listener which runs my game:

```
<div class="content">
<script>
        window.addEventListener('load', Game.start);
</script>
</div>
```

How do I make it so that the JavaScript is contained within the div above it? When it shows, the game is completely outside of it.

I'm using the crafty.js framework.
Documentation here:
http://craftyjs.com/api/

Comment: That's not how it works; usually, the code will decide where it will create new elements. The fact that you added the script within a div is irrelevant.

Comment: So it'd be somewhere within the Javascript of the game framework I'm using?

Comment: Probably. Please add the name of the framework and link to documentation to the question, it should help us find a solution.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://craftyjs.com/api/Crafty-init.html): *Create a div with id cr-stage, if there is not already an HTMLElement with id cr-stage (by Crafty.viewport.init).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, a div with the id "cr-stage" is important to crafty.js.  However, you don't actually have to include it.  If you leave it out, it will automatically be created.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- this is the crafty.js library, which you could load from another server -->
    <script src="crafty.js"></script>

    <!-- this is the script where all your game's JS goes -->
    <script src="mygame.js"></script>

    <script>
      window.addEventListener('load', Game.start);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you use the above, you will get a cr-stage id created for you.

Another thing that might be relevant to your question is if you want to center the cr-stage and remove a small gap that automatically appears above it.  To do that, use this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- this is the crafty.js library, which you could load from another server -->
    <script src="crafty.js"></script>

    <!-- this is the script where all your game's JS goes -->
    <script src="mygame.js"></script>

    <script>
      window.addEventListener('load', Game.start);
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
      /* remove the small gap at the top */
      body { margin-top: 0 }

      /* horizontally center your stage on the page */
      #cr-stage { margin: 0 auto 0 }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what `Game.start` does. However, the script doesn't need to be in the container element. You can simply have something like that:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      // here some library that defines `Game.start`
      window.addEventListener('load', Game.start);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content" id="game-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inside `Game.start` you have to use `document.getElementById("game-container")` in order to get a reference to the element you need, and then use that to add the nodes you want to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give that Div an ID then modify the javascript to load the object in your div's id.